# How to change currently checked RadioButton of RadioButton group in C# properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button

I have a `GroupBox` with a bunch of `RadioButtons`. When they have focus I can use keys up/down to iterate through them.

But when I manually change checked `RadioButton` and press up/down, iteration proceeds from the point it was before changing checked `RadioButton`. The questions are:

- What control handles event corresponds to up/down key click when RadioButton has focus.

**Answer:**
To handle the event of TAB, ESC, RETURN or ARROW buttons `KeyDown` you need to override [`IsInputKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey.aspx) method of the control. Or override `ProcessCmdKey` instead of `KeyDown`.

- How to change currently checked RadioButton properly.

**Answer:**
  Besides setting `radioButton.Checked = true`. You need to set focus on it - `radioButton.Focus()`.

Example:
I have group of 6 RadioButtons (0-5).

- Currently checked is RadioButton No.1 .
- My function changes checked
  RadioButton from No.1 to No.3 .
- User presses Arrow_Up and
  RadioButton No.0 becomes checked instead of No.2.

Comment: Try to set the current tab-index to the selected item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, when the user presses up/down button he/she just moves the focus across radio buttons. so you need to just call method `Focus()` of the button you just set checked property to `true`

Answer (score 2):

1. What event corresponds to up/down key click on `RadioButton`?

   **There is no** event corresponds to the individual `RadioButton`s that you can press a key without releasing but still process the key commands. However, you can override the `ProcessCmdKey` method which your form inherited it from `Form`:

   ```
   protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
       Console.WriteLine("123"); 
       return false; 
   }
   ```
2. How to access internal indexer of `RadioButton` group?

   `TabIndex` property. **There is no** internal index of individual `RadioButton`s. But since you put them on a `GroupBox` which is a `Control`, and have a inherited property named `Controls` is a collection of it's child controls.

The problem presents by the example, appears the problem of `TabIndex`.

`Control` is the base class of most visual components of WinForm applications. It has a parent/child hierarchy, all the `RadioButton`s you put on the `GroupBox` have the same parent, and the `GroupBox` itself owns these `RadioButton`s, and have the property `Controls` which you can access them by index.

Comment: 1) TabIndex holds index of control in group, but i need internal index of currently checked radiobutton.

2) KeyPress and KeyDown don't handle event of pressing up/down arrow. KeyUp event occurs only when button is up, but you can hlod button to scroll radiobuttons.

Comment: 1) The question is: what control handles the event of Arrow_Up KeyDown. If there is no such control, then why currently selected radiobutton changes  
       2) If there is no internal index, then why such problem appears(See example)?  

ProcessCmdKey actually catches pressing Arrow_Up, which solves my problem. But i believe there is better way to solve it and i want to learn what is the source of this problem.

Comment: The remaining question: Which controls KeyDown event should i set, in order to handle pressing Arrow_Up.

Comment: @SkyterX: If you want to perfercy handle any key with holding any long, the best choice would be override `ProcessCmdKey` of the form. The `keyData` can indicates which key is pressed regardless up/down or other keys.

Comment: But why MainForm.KeyDown event can't handle it?

Comment: @SkyterX: It could, you would need to set `KeyPreview` to true and use `MainForm.PreviewKeyDown`. But it doesn't behave as good as `ProcessCmdKey` does, I've ever tested.

Comment: I understand, that i should better use `ProcessCmdKey` function. But i'm curious, what control handles this event.

Comment: I'm asking, because my Function for `MainForm.KeyDown` doesn't handle this event.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the selected radiobutton like this:

```
RadioButton checkedButton = Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

And you could add the checkChanged event to all the radiobuttons.

This will get the index of the radio button thats selected:

```
int index = groupBox1.Controls.IndexOf(groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked));
```

This will select a specific index:

```
groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().ElementAtOrDefault(index).Select();
```

Comment: The problem is not to get checked RadioButton, but correctly change it to another.

Comment: I dont think im understanding the question. do you want to select a radio button according to the current selected radio button?

Comment: I added an example of the problem to my first post.